# How to get user details in WSO2 custom business process handler?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-business-process

I have customized WSO2 ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor. I want to send email with Consumer Key & Consumer Secret to the user. I have ApplicationRegistrationWorkflowDTO object in complete method.

Could you please help me to get user profile details Consumer Key & Consumer Secret using ApplicationRegistrationWorkflowDTO .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` to retrieve user claims. More information is [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs).